# Stop 'run spring-boot' in Intellij from opening browser window

Tags: spring-boot, intellij-idea, vaadin

I have recently installed a fresh version of Vaadin from their website.

As I use the maven command 'Run spring boot' it automatically opens a new browser window.

This is nice the first time, but when you are testing, you end up with 30 windows. It's annoying.

How can you fix that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to remove `LaunchUtil.launchBrowserInDevelopmentMode` to disable the automatic opening of a browser tab.

That is, assuming you have something like the following for your `SpringBootServletInitializer` class.

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        LaunchUtil.launchBrowserInDevelopmentMode(SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args));
    }

}
```

You need to change it to look like the following:

```
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

}
```

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot.